# SPSS: Comparing regression coefficient from multiple models

Tags: regression, spss

Assuming I have price of houses as the dependent variable and the following as the independent variable:

1. Age
2. Area
3. Floor
4. Time taken to walk to nearest railway station (`time_walk`)
5. Time taken to commute, via train, from the nearest station to the CBD station (`time_train`)

Is there a way to compare the coefficient of `time_walk` given different ranges of `time_train`. In essence what I would like to achieve is to investigate  if people value walking differently, given a change in the mrt traveling time.

- Model A: (0-9 mins `time_train`): How would `Walking_Time` affects house pricing?
- Model B: (10-19 mins `time_train`): How would `Walking_Time` affects house pricing?
- Model C: (20-29 mins `time_train`): How would `Walking_Time` affects house pricing?

I understand that I can't create 4 models, each containing only the relevant details (eg. 0-9 mins train time, 10-19 mins train time ...etc) as the n number would be different. This comparing the coefficient estimates wouldn't be fair.

Comment: Can you add a little bit of sample data?
Also, it might be a good idea to post this on Cross-Validated.

My first step would be to make the 4 models and eyeball the results: are they similar, or are there different results?

Comment: Thanks @ChristianSauer, will shift this accordingly

Comment: why not introducing a dummy variable in your model that captures the the differences in train time with regards to walking time.

Comment: note: was cross-posted to https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/112587/17060

Answer (score 0):

What you are suggesting is that the effect of  `walking_time` is dependent on  `time_train`. That's an interaction hypothesis! If `time_train` is an ordinal level variable, you can add interaction terms for each category dummy with the variable `walking_time`. If `time_train` is  a continuous variable, one extra term is sufficient (`walking_time` * `time_train`).