# In R, comparing two regression coefficients from the same model

Tags: r, regression, anova

Using R, I want to statistically compare two coefficients from the same regression. In the Stata software, there is the test B1 = B2. What is the equivalent in R? I check several posts, but no one answered this issue.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33013/what-test-can-i-use-to-compare-slopes-from-two-or-more-regression-models

[SPSS: Comparing regression coefficient from multiple models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25399461/spss-comparing-regression-coefficient-from-multiple-models)

[Comparing regression models in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46145010/comparing-regression-models-in-r)

Here are some simulated data.

```
library('MASS')

mu <- c(0,0,0)

Sigma <- matrix(.5, nrow=3, ncol=3) + diag(3)*0.3

MyData <- mvrnorm(n=10000, mu=mu, Sigma=Sigma) %>% 
  as.data.frame()

names(MyData) = c('v1', 'v2', 'y')

MyModel = lm(y ~ v1 * v2, data = MyData)

summary(MyModel)
```

I want to compare the estimate of V1 to the one of V2. So that if V1 and V2 are manipulated, I would like to tell something like "the influence of V1 on Y, is significantly higher than the influence of V2 on Y"

Comment: note: was cross posted here https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/441024/17060

Comment: You can use `linearHypothesis` from the `car` package, `linearHypothesis(MyModel, "v1 = v2")`. See here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228351/how-to-compare-coefficients-within-the-same-multiple-regression-model

Comment: Please add it as an answer so I can accept it

Comment: Do you know if it works also for logistic regression?

Answer (score 1):

You can try `multcomp` , so if you look at the coefficients of your model:

```
coefficients(MyModel)
(Intercept)           v1           v2        v1:v2 
 0.006961219  0.373547048  0.394760005 -0.012167754
```

You want to find the difference between the 2nd and 3rd term, so your contrast matrix is:

```
# yes it looks a bit weird at first
ctr = rbind("v1-v2"=c(0,1,-1,0))
```

And we can apply this using `glht`:

```
summary(glht(MyModel,ctr))

     Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses

Fit: lm(formula = y ~ v1 * v2, data = MyData)

Linear Hypotheses:
           Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
v1-v2 == 0 -0.02121    0.01640  -1.294    0.196
(Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)
```

This works for most general linear models. In your summary function, you get the the significance of each term based on the effect / standard error. The glht function does something similar. One exception for logistic regression I can think of, is when you have [complete separation](https://blog.minitab.com/blog/starting-out-with-statistical-software/what-is-complete-separation-in-binary-logistic-regression)